# Bootstrap Scrolling Nav Issue

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded a scrolling nav bootstrap template to build up an one-pager. The scrolling works fine and is going smooth to the section I click on. My problem is, when I add another section he jumps onclick to the section, but doesn't animate the scroll. All other menu points are animating the scroll but my new section doesn't. Anybody know the problem?

[Here](https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/) is the link where I downloaded the template.

Comment: You have all the correct js files? That's likely the only question anyone can pose without any code to look at.

Comment: i tried adding new section and it works just fine. Add your code to your question.

Comment: Ok it was my bad! i just forgott to reload the page so that the js didn't reload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you add `page-scroll` to the link since that triggers the animation.

```
<li>
     <a class="page-scroll" href="#more">More</a>
</li>
```

**Demo** http://www.codeply.com/go/rNPxL48Tae